# Azure Blob Storage "Authorization Permission Mismatch" error with azd auth login and DefaultAzureCredential()

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am encountering an "Authorization Permission Mismatch" error when attempting to download a blob from Azure Blob Storage. I authenticate using azd auth login and pass DefaultAzureCredential() to the credential argument in BlobClient. The error message I receive is as follows:

```
<Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code>
<Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

account_url = "https://<your_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net"
container_name = "<your_container_name>"
blob_name = "<your_blob_name>"
container_name = "container_name"
blob_name = "blob_name"


credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=credential, container_name=container_name, blob_name=blob_name)
file = blob_service_client.download_blob()
```

The Storage account has the following roles attached to it:

Storage Blob Data Contributor

Storage Queue Data Contributor

I have verified that the Azure CLI authentication is successful, and I can download the blob using the az storage blob download command without any issues. What could be causing this discrepancy between the Azure CLI command and my Python script? How can I resolve the "Authorization Permission Mismatch" error in my Python script?

Comment: Could you please edit your question by including your python code and confirm whether you assigned roles to user or service principal under storage account?

Comment: I assigned roles to the user and updated the question with code. I am able to see the roles in IAM section of the storage account. Thank you

Comment: Could you try running `az account show` and check with what user account you currently signed in? If it's different from user account assigned with role under storage account, you might get this "Authorization Permission Mismatch" error.

Comment: In my case, I ran `az login` to connect with Azure account and signed in with user account assigned with [role](https://i.imgur.com/T1wXWqw.png) under storage account like [this](https://i.imgur.com/o35s2VC.png). When I ran the python code now, blob downloaded successfully like [this](https://i.imgur.com/isqEVCQ.png)

Comment: Yes, "az account show" displays the correct account. I even tried az login, but I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Could you try running `az logout` first and then login again with `az login`?

Comment: Hi, @pawan Set the subscription ID using `az account set --subscription "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"` if you has multiple account. Refer to this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/manage-azure-subscriptions-azure-cli

Comment: Hello @Venkatesan,
I was able to resolve the issue by deleting %LOCALAPPDATA%\.IdentityService\masai.cache.

az cache purge and az logout did not remove the cache

Answer (score 0):

> `AuthorizationPermissionMismatch` This request is
> not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

The above error occurs when your user or principal doesn't have permission to access the resource(Storage account).

> You can use `az login` to connect with the Azure account and DefaultAzureCredential( ) method.

First, I assigned the **`storage blob data contributor`** role to my storage account as below.

[image]

In my environment, I have some files in my storage account for samples I'm downloading **`dog.jpg`** in my environment.

**Portal:**

[image]

Now, I signed with the **`az login`**  command in my environment and set it up with the subscription ID. if you have If you have **multiple** subscriptions, make sure to set it to **right** subscription in which storage account.

```
az account set --subscription "subscriptionId"
```

[image]

After logging in, I tried the same code with some modifications to download the file from Azure blob storage.

**Code:**

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

account_url = "https://<your_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net"
container_name = "<your_container_name>"
blob_name = "<your_blob_name>"

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=credential)
file = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name,blob=blob_name)
with open(r"C:\Users\xxxxxxx\xxx\xxx\sample.jpg", "wb") as f:
       download_stream = file.download_blob()
       f.write(download_stream.readall())
```

The above code was executed and downloaded the file in my local environment.

**File:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Download a blob with Python - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-download-python)